# codeigniter set_value on corresponding page

Tags: codeigniter

I am building a header search function that is posting to a listings view page which contains a "advanced search" bit. What I would like to do is set the value for the input field called name in the "advanced search" bit on the listing page with the original value of the search before it loads the new view.

So just to summarise:

I have a search function that appears on every page(this is in a template header bit). I would like to capture that search value and set that value on the listing page's advanced search bit.

The functions works as follows:

It posts to a search function within my site controller (site/search). This in turn sends the search results to a listing view (site/listing).

Any advise on how to achieve this little bit of coding will be much appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: how about posting what you have already done, to see what can be optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well either `redirect('site/listing?q='.$this->input->post('search'))`

or

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->library('session'); // Need configuration

$this->session->set_userdata('search', $this->input->post('search'));
redirect('site/listing');
```

and read of the search phrase in list controller through `$this->session->userdata('search')`

It's pretty straightforward.

Basicly calculate the result in the `listing` controller, not the `search`. No point in sending over that much data when you can get it through references.